# Duplicate Customers Returned in Quickbooks CustomerQueryRq

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

We have an application that is synchronizing Quickbook's customers with a remote SQL Server database.  And, I am running into a bizarre issue with the QBXML CustomerQueryRs.  I am using an iterator with varying slice count and the response XML intermittently returns the exact same customer 2 or more times.

I have verified that the customer is exactly the same (i.e. FullName and ListID) are identical.  I have even run the query with a MaxReturned value of 1500 which is greater than the number of customers in the company file.  Some customers are returned as many as 5 times in the QBXML response.

Below, is a copy of my last request using the large MaxReturned value.  My response is huge so, I will not include it.  But, the same CustomerRet element is returned more than one time for about 133 customers out of around 1400.  Any suggestions?

** QBXML REQUEST **

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="12.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><CustomerQueryRq metaData="MetaDataAndResponseData" iterator="Start"><MaxReturned>1500</MaxReturned><ActiveStatus>ActiveOnly</ActiveStatus></CustomerQueryRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting back different notes or one of the other fields is changing.

Go to c:\ProgramData\Intuit\QuickBooks and edit the qbsdk.ini file.
If qbsdk.ini is not there, just create it.

Add or modify the following lines:
[Parser]
SdkAccelerator=N